# When did Dumbledore know Harry was going to die?

Tags: harry-potter

When did Albus Dumbledore first realise that Harry Potter was going to die?

I tried re-reading the books but I cannot find it...thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the fact that Harry _had_ to "die" in order for Voldy to be killed?

Answer (score 4):

**Ever since Harry escaped death from Voldemort in 1981.**

> McGonagall asks: "How in the name of heaven did Harry survive?"
>
> "We can only guess," said Dumbledore.
>
> *The Philosopher's Stone*

He had already guessed how Harry survived, which would be that; the curse had rebounded > Harry became an accidental horcrux > He has to die one day, in order for Voldemort to be truly dead.

Further reinforced here:

> I guessed, nearly fifteen years ago," said Dumbledore, "when I saw the scar upon your forehead, what it might mean. I guessed that it might be the sign of a connection forged between you and Voldemort."
>
> *Order of the Phoenix*

His 'guess' is pretty much true, stated here:

> "And you knew this? You knew--all along?"
>
> "I guessed. But my guesses have usually been good," said Dumbledore.
>
> *The Deathly Hallows*

So, Dumbledore had already knew, that Harry was going to die eventually(in order to get rid of Voldemort), when Harry survived Voldemort's attack.

Comment: Of course, this makes it extra creepy that his other response to the scar (when McGonagall asked if it could be healed) was something like "I would not change it even if I could" - very cold, when he knows the end result.

Comment: @Megha, I think he was talking about the *literal* scar at that point.  Healing the scar would not have removed the fragment of Voldemort's soul.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - well, there was also that bit about scars coming in handy, which doesn't make sense if he was talking about the literal flesh, but might if he was talking about the rest of it.  Shrug.  There's a little too much evidence Dumbles is evil for me to assume that is not what he meant